# Azure get the blob icon with the url

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there any way you can extract the uploaded blob icon from the url address?

I've tried  `System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("blobazureurl")` but it did not work.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Is your blob publicly accessible? Or in other words, when you type blob url in the browser, do you see the image or get a resource not found error?

Comment: Ahhh no its private. Any way to go around it without setting it as public? Do i have to use a SAS url :S?

Comment: SAS URL is your friend :).

Comment: Gaaaah alright thanks haha

Comment: Im still not getting any image. Am i missing some code? Its nothing wrong with the sasuri.

Comment: Check the content-type property of the blob. At times incorrect property of the blob also prevents rendering of the blob.